# Validar una lista desplegable con un boton que abre una ventana modal en bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net

Tengo un botón que me despliega una ventana modal con bootstrap.

```html
<button id="btnPrueba" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#VentanaProducto" style="height: auto; background-color: lightgray;">
```

Pero ahora necesito evaluar antes de desplegar la ventana modal que de la siguiente lista haya sido seleccionado Argentina

```html
<select name="Comb" id="Contenido" class="form-control">
 <option value="0">-</option>
 <option value="12">Argentina</option>
 <option value="44">Colombia</option>
</select>
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no entiendo muy bien tu pregunta. Pero según lo que conseguí  entender te hice una pequeña demo.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>DEMO </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <select name="Comb" id="Contenido" class="form-control">
      <option value="0">-</option>
      <option value="12">Argentina</option>
      <option value="44">Colombia</option>
    </select>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        aqui la informacion
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Y tu archivo js seria algo por el estilo.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Contenido").change(function(){
    //Seleccionar el value del campo seleccionado.
    var val = $(this).find('option:selected').val();

    //Significa que es Argentina en este caso.
    if(val == 12){
     //Mostramos el modal
     $("#exampleModal").modal('show');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero sería hacer un evento cuando ocurra el clic sobre el botón.

Lo siguiente sería obtener el valor del select y lo comparas con tu resultado

Y luego por último muestras tu modal.

```js
$('#validador').click(function(){
  var select =$('#contenido').val();
  if(select == 12){
    $('#myModal').modal('show')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select name="Comb" id="contenido" class="form-control">
 <option value="0">-</option>
 <option value="12">Argentina</option>
 <option value="44">Colombia</option>
</select>

<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="validador">
  Launch demo modal
</a>
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Agrega una explicación de por qué tu código funciona y soluciona el problema planteado, "espero te sirva" no es suficiente.

Comment: Ya lo edite @Shaz

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con Jquery, creando el evento onclick y comprobando el valor:

```
<button id="btnPrueba" type="button" data-toggle="modal" style="height: auto; background-color: lightgray;" onclick="validar()">


<script>

    function validar(){

        if ($("#Contenido").val() == "12")
        {
            $('#VentanaProducto').modal('show');
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

No entendí muy bien lo de desplegar; no sé si te refieres al mostrar el modal o al cerrarlo. Como sea, usa la propiedad

```
$("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
    // evento al cerrar el modal
});
```

o

```
$("#myModal").on("show.bs.modal", function () {
    // evento al mostrar el modal
});
```

Y dentro puedes capturar los datos antes que se muestre o cuando se oculte el modal.

En tu caso, obviamente usarías el id de tu modal: `$("#btnPrueba")`.